# UDP: Receive answer from another IP

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

Let's say i have this context:
i'm Listening on 85.222.45.1:1156.

A client, with source Src IP:92.35.21.6 Src Port:6320 send a packet to Dst IP: 85.222.45.1 Dst Port:1156

The server answers to client address Dst IP:92.35.21.6 Dst Port:6320 but from another address, let's say Src IP: 101.344.53.12 Src Port: 1156

Is that possible?

I think that may be possible, only if the application is able to understand what packet belongs to a determined session based on content of UDP packet. So in this case, the only way to connect sessions is based on Port recognition and UDP packet.

What do you think?

EDIT: This happens because of a load balancing configuration.
So i was just wondering.

Comment: Why? Why does the server answer from another address? Why doesn't it answer via the same socket it received the request on?

Comment: Because in this case, i had to fight with the load balancing. That's the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate every outgoing packets, so basically you can change the IP block of your response (if you are the server). But I can't see any reason to do something like this.